# collagePlus grid not fitting container

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make a grid of images using the collagePlus JQuery plugin. This is supposed to fit all the images in a div within the container.
However, when I try inserting more than say 4 images, it goes beyond the height of the container to fit the images instead of reducing the image dimensions to fit the container.

The code:

```
<html>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="css/collage.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.collagePlus.js"></script>
    <div style='height:200px; width:100%;max-height:200px;'>
    <div class="Collage">
        <img src="four.png"/>
        <img src="four.png"/>
        <img src="four.png"/>
        <img src="four.png"/>
        <img src="four.png"/>
        <img src="four.png"/>
        <img src="four.png"/>
        <img src="four.png"/>

    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('.Collage').collagePlus({'allowPartialLastRow' : true});
    </script>
</html>
```

If anyone knows why this is happening and what I can do to fix it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle? according to this url http://jsfiddle.net/edlea/uZv3n/ it seems pretty easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Try using target height for each rows

```
$('.Collage').collagePlus(
{
    // change this to adjust the height of the rows
    'targetHeight' : 100,
    // change this to try different effects
    // valid effets = effect-1 to effect-6
    'effect' : "effect-1"
}
);
```

Comment: I did try this, and it works well till the images fit exactly in the container ( 10 images right now). The moment I add an 11th image, it overflows.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a different plugin, or code it yourself. Collage Plus doesn't appear to have a "fixed height" capability, it only has the `targetHeight` attribute to set the height of each row. Unfortunately this makes it about as dynamic as a crayon.

Here's some [example code](http://jsfiddle.net/husbwf1t/) (Code snippet doesn't appear to work in Google Chrome):

```js
$('.Collage').collagePlus({'allowPartialLastRow': true, 'targetHeight': 95});
```

```css
#Container {
    border:1px solid black;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    max-height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.Collage {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ed-lea.github.io/jquery-collagePlus/javascripts/example/jquery.collagePlus.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container">
    <div class="Collage"><!-- Remove all whitespace between elements as suggested on collagePlus
        --><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /><!--
        --><img src="http://placehold.it/320x100" alt="" /><!--
        --><img src="http://placehold.it/550x400" alt="" /><!--
        --><img src="http://placehold.it/120x150" alt="" /><!--
        --><img src="http://placehold.it/120x150" alt="" /><!--
        --><img src="http://placehold.it/315x205" alt="" /><!--
        --><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /><!--
    --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay I just modified the targetHeight to make sure all my images fit. The problem is I'm using them in a carousel, so the overflow looks ugly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

even though this is a year old post, maybe this can help someone.

Set your images to float:left and change line 80 of collagePlus from

```
var w = (typeof $img.data("width") != 'undefined') ? $img.data("width") : $img.width(), 
h = (typeof $img.data("height") != 'undefined') ? $img.data("height") : $img.height();
```

to

```
var w = $img.width(),h = $img.height();
```

Sometimes width and height of images were returning 0. I'm also using http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/ to reset collage.